# xPath problem matching specific attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I've got the following HTML that I am trying to pull the state attribute out of.

```
<div id="content" class="listing mapListing" longitude="123.0000" latitude="-123.0000" listingName="business" business=";12345678;;;;evar01=name" state="NSW" events="1">
```

I'm trying to match using the following PHP, which doesn't return "NSW".

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($html); 
    foreach ($xpath->query("//div[@id='content']") as $item) { 
              echo $item->getAttribute("state");
    }
```

However, the following; returns "listing" (instead of "listing mapListing") and my suspicion is the space is causing issues

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($html); 
        foreach ($xpath->query("//div[@id='content']") as $item) { 
                  echo $item->getAttribute("class");
        }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can match against "state" attribute?

Comment: It _does_ return 'NSW' here... (PHP 5.3.2, libxml2 2.7.7).

Comment: Oh, and I also get `listing mapListing`. Are you 100% sure you're looking at the right document & node? Wat does `$item->ownerDocument->saveXML($item);` get you?

Comment: Or `$xpath->query("//div[@id='content']/@state");` for that matter..

Comment: Thanks guys, I've got an issue somewhere else. I'm tracking down the problem now ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the html namespace via xmlns in the document? Then PHP won't find any element unless you register the namespace:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($html);
$xpath->registerNamespace('html', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'); // or smth else
    foreach ($xpath->query("//html:div[@id='content']") as $item) { 
              echo $item->getAttribute("state");
    }
```